# how to show records that are different from the where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that I am doing, what I need is to show only the records that do not match the where clause.

**mechanic_client**

| id | user_id | mechanic_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 31 | 13 |
| 16 | 34 | 1 |
| 26 | 61 | 1 |

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lucas |
| 31 | mauricio |
| 34 | pedro |
| 61 | carlos |

The user admin lucas created Pedro and Carlos, they are created both in the users table and in the mechanic_client table, so what I want is not to show Pedro and Carlos, only show the other users, but the function does not work for me it continues to show me to all users.

**function index**

```
 $users_mechanics = DB::table('mechanic_client')->get();

        foreach ($users_mechanics as $user_mechanic) {
            
            $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('roles')->where('id', '<>', $user_mechanic->user_id)->paginate(10);


            return [
                'pagination' => [
                    'total'         => $users->total(),
                    'current_page'  => $users->currentPage(),
                    'per_page'      => $users->perPage(),
                    'last_page'     => $users->lastPage(),
                    'from'          => $users->firstItem(),
                    'to'            => $users->lastItem(),
                ],
                'users' => $users
            ];
        
            
        }
```

**query return**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lucas |
| 31 | mauricio |

it should look like this

Thanks for the help..

Comment: you can do it without for each loop but your question not getting properly, in this based on which condition removed Pedro and Carlos users?

Comment: I don't know why you are using the foreach loop. It is not a good way to run query in foreach. I just want to know do you want to show users which are not in mechanic_client table?

Comment: you might be able to use `doesntHave` so you query would look something like `User:: doesntHave('mechanic')->get()` and remove foreach loop now sure why you have it there

Comment: When performing the distinct, you should not see Carlos or Pedro @AnkitaDobariya

Comment: what I want is to show the other users except pedro nor carlos from the users table @Yogendra

Comment: @LucasCardemilVillegas want to show the other users except pedro nor carlos but based on which condition?

Comment: you can do it direct ,exactly not getting point.              User::whereIn('id',MechanicClient::where('mechanic_id','!=',1)->pluck('user_id')->toArray())
                           ->with('roles')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

Comment: if they exist in the mechanic_client table, do not show them in the users table @AnkitaDobariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MechanicClient Model
<?php

 namespace App\Model;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MechanicClient extends Model {

  public $table = 'mechanic_client';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'mechanic_id',
 ];
}
```

In User Model

```
public function mechanic() {
    return $this->hasone('App\Model\MechanicClient', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

And check In Controller

```
User::doesntHave('mechanic')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Hope fully it will help to you.

Comment: Thanks incredible, and I'm sorry if I don't explain it well @AnkitaDobariya

Comment: Happy to help you :)